# How to select an embeded video using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I website I am using has embedded youtube videos, like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/spBaumdWlgQ?feature=oembed">
```

I don't have access to the code, just whatever I can do in the console.

Eventually I want to change the play rate beyond what youtube UI allows. But I can't select the video

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
```

Video does not exist!

(If I inspect the video, it eventually becomes visible to the `document` but that's beside the point.

I eventually want to do this

```
video.playbackRate = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **select the iframe**, then **select the element** inside iframe.

This may work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0]
```

Comment: It gives an error of `Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.notion.so" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: its because CORS policy,You need control over the domain you want to embed to remove/amend its CORS policy. It the domain has explicitely blocked Cross-Origin requests, there's nothing you can do about it.

This is used to avoid anyone hijacking any site you want (you could have a full screen Google in an iframe running with your ads on top on bettergoogle.com, things like that).
https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b
This page will give you more insights on Cross-Origin

Comment: Is there no other way to control the playrate in this case

Answer (score 1):

To access any element inside iframe you need to access `contentWindow` property of iframe. Which in turn returns the `window` object. Use this window object to access anything inside an iframe.

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'),video;
     if (iframe) {
         video = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('video');
     }
  
      if (video) {
           video.playbackRate = 3
      }
```

**But one thing, since this is youtube video's iframe, you will face the CORS issue. And so you won't be able to manipulate iframe data**
*

> Refer [here](https://benohead.com/blog/2015/12/07/cross-document-communication-with-iframes/) to know more about the CORS issue in an iframe

Comment: how come chrome extensions can bypass the CORS issue. I ran the code you also mentioned and I got the CORS issue, but then I installed a chrome extension which adds controls to the video and they are able (I'm assuming) to get hold of the contentWindow!